# how to add a capacitor whitelist plugin to ionic app

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

When using cordova the documentation is clear as to how i can add some urls to cordova whitlist so that they can be opened using in app browser on my ionic app.

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare

and then in the config.xml 
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />

<!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix
     to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
```

But i am not using cordova rather capacitor
and i cant find any information how to add a whitelist plugin using capacitor and where the config.xml will be ? any suggestion as to how to go about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Just npm install the plugin, capacitor allows all connections

```
npm install cordova-plugin-whitelist
npx cap sync
```

Comment: capacitor allows all connections in app ?

Comment: my issue was that it redirected to browser outside the app

Comment: Sorry, you were talking about cordova plugins. Cordova whitelist plugin has no effect on capacitor itself, just on other cordova plugins. For allowing internal capacitor navigation there is the allowNavigation entry in capacitor.config.json https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Comment: i saw that but after adding this tag in capacitor.config.json , i  make a ionic capcitor sync ios and it deletes it

Comment: i understand that sync tries to make all external changes syncronized with whats in ios, but how can i add this so that after making ionic building it does not disapper

Comment: I've tested running `ionic capacitor sync ios` and it doesn't remove the values I entered. Make sure you are using latest ionic CLI and that you are editing the root `capacitor.config.json` file, not the one that appears in Xcode as that's a copy of the file and gets rewritten with root values on copy/sync commands.

Comment: yes that was one issue i was editing the one in xcode thanks, but i still have such situation that it redirects but without the token in the url

Comment: i dont know if you are familiar with keycloak but i was redirecting to keycloak account page, i am using keycloak for logging and user management, issue is it redirects to the logiin page and asks to login in again, after login when you click account it goes back to login, this does not happen on the android version

Comment: basically on android version it remembers that we are already logged in, it keeps the session, but on ios we are redirected to login again

Comment: you should not really navigate to external servers inside your capacitor app for oauth flow, you should use Browser, InAppBrowser, aerogear-cordova-oauth2 or some other oauth plugin

Comment: anyway, that's a different topic, better create a new thread

Comment: thanks this is a thread to my new question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251756/navigating-to-keycloak-account-from-capacitor-app